# Recursive open files in Perl

Tags: perl, file, recursion

I have a Perl script to count how many times an expression appered in a file, in this particular case it counts everything found between '<' and '>' because i wanted it to parse .xml files.

**SCRIPT:**

```
#usr/bin/perl

sub by_count {
   $count{$b} <=> $count{$a};
}

open(INPUT, "<[Content_Types].xml");
open(OUTPUT, ">output");
$bucket = qw/./;


while(<INPUT>){
   @words = split(/\</);

   foreach $word (@words){
            if($word=~/($bucket*>)/io){

      #print OUTPUT "$word";
      #print OUTPUT "\n\n";
      $count{$1}++;}

   }
}
foreach $word (sort by_count keys %count) {

   print OUTPUT "<$word occurs $count{$word} times\n\n";

}

close INPUT;
close OUTPUT;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<Default Extension="xlsx" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"/> occurs 1 times

<Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/> occurs 1 times

<Override PartName="/word/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml"/> occurs 1 times
```

**PROBLEM**

I want to do it recursively. I have a directory with multiple subdirectories inside, and inside each subfolder there is a [Content_Types].xml file. Any suggestion on how to parse every file with that name found in the main directory?

**Example diagram:**

```
>Directory
  >Directory1
    >[Content_Types].xml
  >Directory2
    >[Content_Types].xml
  >Directory3
    >[Content_Types].xml
  .
  .
  .

  >Directory100
    >[Content_Types].xml
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use module `Find::File` that will traverse all subdirectories to find what you tell it. It would be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;

find( \&wanted, shift );

sub wanted {
        return unless -f $_ && m/\[Content_Types\]\.xml/;
        open my $fh, '<', $_ or do {
                warn qq|WARNING: Could not open $File::Find::name\n|;
                return;
        };  
        open my $ofh, '>', 'output';
        my $bucket = qw/./;

        while ( <$fh> ) { 
                ## ... your code here ...
        }   

        ## ... your code here ...
}
```

Give as argument the directory you want the search to begin:

```
perl script.pl .
```

Comment: @BrunoAlexandre: The `wanted` function is nearly the same as your script but executed once for each xml file. The `while ( <$fh> ) { ... }` is like your `while` and after that you execute a `foreach`. So same here. Also I use lexically scoped variables for the `open` functions. I think it's better coding and safer.

Comment: I'm getting errors:

Global symbol "@words" requires explicit package name at yetanother.pl line 21.
Global symbol "$word" requires explicit package name at yetanother.pl line 22.
Global symbol "%count" requires explicit package name at yetanother.pl line 26.


Can you merge my code and yours and post it here please?

Comment: @BrunoAlexandre: That's because I added the `warnings` and `strict` modules. They force you to declare your variables, and much more, doing code clearer and safer. Also you can comment those two lines and forget all I said.

Comment: And +1 for using 3 parameter open.

Comment: Thamks. I still get: invalid top directory at /usr/share/perl/5.14/File/Find.pm 
Any idea?

Comment: @BrunoAlexandre: Please. Read the whole answer and pay attention. I say at the end that you must provide a directory as argument to the script. I tested with `.` but it should work with wathever you use, `/home/me/my/folder` for example.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, i did forget the argument. Done that and now the following error:
 Undefined subroutine in sort at yetanother.pl line 31, <$fh> line 2.

Comment: @BrunoAlexandre: Never mind. In your original code the `sort` function uses a special subrutine, is declared and implemented?

Comment: I don't know, i editted this code from a script to count word ocurrencies in a text file, i'm not yet familiar with perl sintax since i just started learning it like 3 days ago. Sorry

Comment: @BrunoAlexandre: Your `sort` function uses the subrutine `by_count` to get keys in a special order. You must have that subrutine implemented as you had in the original script. Add it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience it's finaly working. Just one more thing, i can get it to print in the console but not in a textfile (it generates a blank textfile) any idea why is this?

Comment: @BrunoAlexandre: Substitute `OUTPUT` with `$ofh` in your print statement.

Comment: Now won't create a text file. But it's cool i can simply output in the terminal and copy it to a text file

Comment: You could simplify `m/\[Content_Types\]\.xml/` to `/\Q[Content_Types].xml/`

Comment: Still not working and the terminal only outputs a limited amount of characters

Comment: @BrunoAlexandre: Edit your question (or create a new one) with what you have, what you expect and the error is happening. It's difficult for me to help only guessing.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really necessary to do this recursively. It works very well iteratively.

Define a stack of directories:

```
my @directories;
```

Then push the start directory into the list:

```
push(@directories, "startdirectory");
```

Finally, as a loop, you can do:

```
while(my $dir=shift(@directories))
```

then, for every traversed directory, push all found subdirectories onto the list. After that, look for the files and parse them as needed (i.e. add your code listed above).

Hint: You can check if something is a directory with (-d myfile).

Comment: I'm getting an error. Could you please add those lines to my code and put it here complete?